# How to initialize object with CodeDOM?

Tags: c#, codedom

I need to initialize my object like below:

```
var obj = new EduBranch {
    Id = model.Id,
    WorklevelId = model.WorklevelId,
    EdulevelId = model.EdulevelId,
    Title = model.Title,
    StartEduYearId = model.StartEduYearId,
    EndEduYearId = model.EndEduYearId,
};
```

but in CodeDOM I could only find:

```
var objectCreate1 = new CodeObjectCreateExpression("EduBranch", 
    new CodeExpression[]{});
```

and this is using parentheses to initialize instead of brackets. 
is there a CodeDOM approach for this? ( I already make my code using stringBuilder but I'm looking for a CodeDOM approach )   thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CodeDom doesn't currently support [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) (or collection initializers, for that matter).

The CodeDom has fallen out of favor over the years, because of other technologies ([T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), for example).

That said, because this line:

```
var obj = new EduBranch {
    Id = model.Id,
    WorklevelId = model.WorklevelId,
    EdulevelId = model.EdulevelId,
    Title = model.Title,
    StartEduYearId = model.StartEduYearId,
    EndEduYearId = model.EndEduYearId,
};
```

Is effectively the same as:

```
var obj = new EduBranch();

obj.Id = model.Id;
obj.WorklevelId = model.WorklevelId;
obj.EdulevelId = model.EdulevelId;
obj.Title = model.Title;
obj.StartEduYearId = model.StartEduYearId;
obj.EndEduYearId = model.EndEduYearId;
```

You can use the CodeDOM to generate the above, and get the same

Comment: T4 is code generation for dummies.  Yes, it has it's place for small, quick projects, but there is still no substitute for a large-scale web service or enterprise application than CodeDOM.  The only complaint I have about it is the lack of support for generic types.  Other than that, there's just no substitute when you have real work to do.